# How to format the notion import markdown code

Tags: markdown, notion-api

I use `typora` to write `markdown` documents, but I want to import to `notion` for viewing anywhere, but during the `import` process, there are problems with missing `pictures` and `wrong code formatting`

The following example

- image

```
//  typora
![img](kubelet-cri.assets/793142dff34819e40f5dcc44401372c1.png)
```

import to notion

```
//  notion
This iamage couldn't to
```

- code

```
// typora
// cmd/kubelet/app/options/options.go
// AddFlags adds flags for a specific KubeletFlags to the specified FlagSet
func (f *KubeletFlags) AddFlags(mainfs *pflag.FlagSet) {        // line 294
    ...
    // EXPERIMENTAL FLAGS
    fs.StringVar(&f.RemoteRuntimeEndpoint, "container-runtime-endpoint", f.RemoteRuntimeEndpoint, "[Experimental] The endpoint of remote runtime service. Currently unix socket endpoint is supported on Linux, while npipe and tcp endpoints are supported on windows. Note: When using docker as container runtime this specifies the dockershim socket location which kubelet itself creates.  Examples:'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', 'npipe:////./pipe/dockershim'")
    fs.StringVar(&f.RemoteImageEndpoint, "image-service-endpoint", f.RemoteImageEndpoint, "[Experimental] The endpoint of remote image service. If not specified, it will be the same with container-runtime-endpoint by default. Currently unix socket endpoint is supported on Linux, while npipe and tcp endpoints are supported on windows.  Examples:'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', 'npipe:////./pipe/dockershim'")
    ...   
}
```

import to notion

```
// notion
// cmd/kubelet/app/options/options.go// AddFlags adds flags for a specific KubeletFlags to the specified FlagSetfunc (f *KubeletFlags) AddFlags(mainfs *pflag.FlagSet) {        // line 294    ...    // EXPERIMENTAL FLAGS    fs.StringVar(&f.RemoteRuntimeEndpoint, "container-runtime-endpoint", f.RemoteRuntimeEndpoint, "[Experimental] The endpoint of remote runtime service. Currently unix socket endpoint is supported on Linux, while npipe and tcp endpoints are supported on windows. Note: When using docker as container runtime this specifies the dockershim socket location which kubelet itself creates.  Examples:'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', 'npipe:////./pipe/dockershim'")    fs.StringVar(&f.RemoteImageEndpoint, "image-service-endpoint", f.RemoteImageEndpoint, "[Experimental] The endpoint of remote image service. If not specified, it will be the same with container-runtime-endpoint by default. Currently unix socket endpoint is supported on Linux, while npipe and tcp endpoints are supported on windows.  Examples:'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', 'npipe:////./pipe/dockershim'")    ...}
```

The image problem seems to be that `typora caches the network image locally`, importing the local image, but for the `code problem`, this seems to remove the newlines causing the format error

How to solve this? I really appreciate any help with this.